# Parshas Haman on Tuesday of Beshalach

Tags: beshalach, segulah, mon-manna, tefilla

What is the Significance of Saying the Parshas Haman on the Tuesday of Beshalach and how is it done?

Comment: closely related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/130679

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see my discussion of the basis and meaning of it here:
http://parsha.blogspot.com/2007/01/explaining-my-flippancy-yesterday-about.html

It is a segulah from R' Mendel Mi-Rimanov, though it is sourced (in different form) as early as Rav Amram Gaon, and even earlier, in the Yerushalmi. But one does not have to leap on to every segulah, as it becomes the latest fad and spreads virally via email.

Comment: Would it not be nice if people leaped on this segula, recited the parshas haMan with kavana and actually grew in their Emuna and Bitachon? Probabaly the kind of segula to be encouraged in this age of red bindelach and schlissel Challas.